# The following Python program for prime factorization does not work

Tags: python-3.x, prime-factoring

I am relatively new to Python. Now, I know there are tons of better programs for prime factorization out there but I tried writing the code without any help and got stuck. Here is the code:

```
def is_prime(n):
    i =2
    while i<n:
        if n%i==0:
            return False
        i+=1
    return True
def prime_factor(n):
    b = n
    factor=[]
    i = 2
    while i<b and is_prime(i):
        while n%i ==0:
            factor.append(i)
            n/=i
            continue
        i+=1
    return factor
print (prime_factor(28))
```

The code works well for some numbers (27, 24, 12, 18 etc) but fails for 28. I get the output as `[2,2]` for the value 28. Where does the fault lie?

Answer (score 0):

Problem in `while` condition:

```
while i<b :
    while is_prime(i) and n%i ==0:
        factor.append(i)
        n/=i
        continue
    i+=1
```